# How to add Content Security Policy to Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I have a plugin which I have to support both on Chrome and Firefox browsers. The plugin does cross script loading.

In Chrome, by adding the content security policy in my *manifest.json* file, I could get away with it. How can I do it Firefox extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a simple solution for my problem and upon looking up some firefox plugin extensions i had to come up with my own solution as below. The below solution was tested on FF 24.0 but should work on other versions as well.

```
Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService)
    .addObserver(_httpExamineCallback, "http-on-examine-response", false);

function _httpExamineCallback(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);

    if (httpChannel.responseStatus !== 200) {
        return;
    }

    var cspRules;
    var mycsp;
    // thre is no clean way to check the presence of csp header. an exception
    // will be thrown if it is not there.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel
    try {    
        cspRules = httpChannel.getResponseHeader("Content-Security-Policy");
        mycsp = _getCspAppendingMyHostDirective(cspRules);
        httpChannel.setResponseHeader('Content-Security-Policy', mycsp, false);
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            // Fallback mechanism support             
            cspRules = httpChannel.getResponseHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy");
            mycsp = _getCspAppendingMyHostDirective(cspRules);    
            httpChannel.setResponseHeader('X-Content-Security-Policy', mycsp, false);            
        } catch (e) {
            // no csp headers defined
            return;
        }
    }

};

/**
 * @var cspRules : content security policy 
 * For my requirement i have to append rule just to 'script-src' directive. But you can
 * modify this function to your need.
 *
 */
function _getCspAppendingMyHostDirective(cspRules) {
  var rules = cspRules.split(';'),
    scriptSrcDefined = false,
    defaultSrcIndex = -1;

  for (var ii = 0; ii < rules.length; ii++) {
    if ( rules[ii].toLowerCase().indexOf('script-src') != -1 ) {
        rules[ii] = rules[ii] + ' <My CSP Rule gets appended here>';
        scriptSrcDefined = true;
    }

    if (rules[ii].toLowerCase().indexOf('default-src') != -1) {
        defaultSrcIndex = ii;
    }
}

  // few publishers will put every thing in the default (default-src) directive,
  // without defining script-src. We need to modify those as well.
  if ((!scriptSrcDefined) && (defaultSrcIndex != -1)) {
    rules[defaultSrcIndex] = rules[defaultSrcIndex] + ' <My CSP rule gets appended here>';
  }

  return rules.join(';');
};
```

Comment: Fyi, this does work but will not be accepted by Mozilla into the Addons gallery (I just tried).

Comment: @AchalDave what was their reason? Tell the editor that it has to be done, otherwise we cant import jquery library chartjs library etc. There is no other way. Either editor thought you were doing something malicious and you have to prove that you arent, or he thought you were doing something you arent. So just talk to the guy. Or you may be doing this when you dont need to. And also ask editor for an alternative way to accomplish what you need, be sure to share that way with us please.

Comment: I tried asking both the reviewer and the #extdev channel, and I was informed in both places that I couldn't have remote code - that I need to bundle the scripts I use with the addon. With, e.g., jQuery, this is fine, but I don't know how to do this with MathJax, where the script relies on numerous things server side (it seems).

Comment: Does this go in a background script or a content script? Maybe you have some example source that you can point us to.

Comment: @N-ate sorry i don't have any code samples of it. It has been very long time since i have worked on it and not sure if the current browser version supports it.
As far as i remember it has to be done in the background script.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are plans in the future to add content policy natively in the SDK ([bug 852297](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=852297)), but there is a 3rd party module that should get you close to where you want to be: [policy.js](https://github.com/clarkbw/addon-pathfinder/blob/master/lib/content/policy.js)